# ko.mapping.toJS not retrieving field value for multiple select

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-select2

I'm using Knockout with Select2.

This is the Select2 Container:

```
<div class="select2-container select2-container-multi" id="s2id_edit_field_opportunity_list" style="width: 226px;">
    <ul class="select2-choices">
        <li class="select2-search-choice">
            <div>Post Tier II</div>
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-search-field">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitilize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" id="s2id_autogen38" style="width: 10px;">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>*
```

And the hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" data-bind="attr: {disabled: $root.freezeForm, id: field_id}, value: $root[field_name], select2: {data: {results: options}, multiple: true }" id="edit_field_opportunity_list" tabindex="-1" class="select2-offscreen" value="Post Tier II">
```

Here's the submit code:

```
saveItem: function()
            {
                var self = this,
                saveData = ko.mapping.toJS(self);
                saveData._token = csrf;
                console.dir(saveData)
                ...
```

which logs an empty value for the field opportunities_list:

```
Object_token: "GgWevTcnil1lc93FUaQE2Rmla57JDQonAQArF4Bg"
bc_sales_person: "Eric"
budget: "94400.00"
client_billing_contact: "fdf"
client_billing_email: "joa@a.com"
client_name: "Benjamin Roberts"
coin: "GBP"
flight_from: "2014-10-14"
flight_to: "2014-10-31"
id: "7"
opportunity_list: ""
payment_term: "Net 60"
tracking_platform: "IdevAffiliate"
```

Any ideas why the value is not mapped?

Comment: It might be helpful to reproduce the issue in a JSFiddle.  What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Not an error message. Just the opportunity_list field empty.

Comment: You need to post more code to help you